# Can not access files in any folder on Samsung Galaxy SII

Tags: files, android, samsung, phone

When I connect my Samsung Galaxy SII with USB cable my DCIM folder looks empty although I can see my files on phone. Do you have any idea what would be the problem?

On computer:

[image: Empty folder]

On phone:

[image]

Comment: Have you connected the SGSII via Mass storage?, i get Filesystem 11GB when i connect mine.

Comment: It is connected as MTP.

Comment: Got to Settings>Applications>Turn on USB debugging mode. I don't really remember how was it with Samsung ROM's as I'm Using MIUI but look trhough the Application settings and the Storage Settings.

Comment: A workaround would be to use Kies Airweb interface , so you can connect through a web browser and download your files to your PC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While USB Debugging option is disabled Samsung Galaxy SII is working as a MTP device and in this case Ubuntu can not see files on the phone. When I enable USB debugging option and connect my phone with USB cable Ubuntu recognise my phone as USB mass storage device and I can access my files.

Comment: this worked for me, but i had to  disable-reenable USB debugging mode multiple times and even restart the phone once!

Answer (score 4):

The way to get direct USB access to files on the Galaxy is as posted here: http://www.tuxtrix.com/2011/07/how-to-access-samsung-galaxy-s-ii-usb.html

This is not about USB debugging but simple telling the Galaxy to connect its storage to PC via USB:

On the Galaxy do:
Menu -> Settings -> Wireless and network -> USB utilities -> Connect Storage to PC

Comment: You are talking about ICS way

Comment: I don't have "USB Utilities" in my options.

Answer (score 2):

Could not get Galaxy SII to work via Kies wireless or plugged in to USB directly on Ubuntu 11.10. As others mentioned, the way I fixed was going to "Settings>Applications>Development>Turn on USB debugging" on my phone and then reconnecting with USB cable to my laptop. I put my music in '/media/audio' (copied from my local ~/music folder) and it just worked! Kies would be nice to get working though, so I wouldn't even need a cable...it connects and I can see all my content...it just won't upload anything. Thanks for the answers guys, this has been bugging me for weeks since I got my S II.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working this way.
On your Galaxy tab go to :Settings->Wireless&Network->USB Settings-> select Mass Storage.
Then connect the Galaxy tab to your computer and select "mount"

Answer (score 1):

On my S4 mini, even after enabling USB debugging, the phone was connected as a "MTP" device, and I couldn't see any files on it.

In the phone's "Notifications", I had to tap on "Connected as a Media device", and change that to "Connect as Camera (PTP)".

Then, I could see the files under ~/.gvfs/...

Answer (score 0):

There is [a PPA with upstream MTP patches for gvfs](https://launchpad.net/~langdalepl/+archive/gvfs-mtp) built in. Upgrading to this is fairly simple but *may* be unstable or you might not trust it. That is your decision to make.

Installing it is fairly simple:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:langdalepl/gvfs-mtp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

You'll want to log out and in (or restart) after doing that but you should then be able to use MTP from within Nautilus.